# Declaring a Filehandle in Python

Tags: python, declaration, filehandle

I need to do a try block on open but I want my variable to be available externally:

```
inputFile = null #This is the line that I don't know how to write
try:
    inputFile = open( sys.argv[0] )
except IOError as e:
    print "ERROR: Could not open " + sys.argv[0]

#use inputFile here
```

Comment: In python, the equivalent to null is `None`

Comment: `try` and `except` are not scopes.  Variables you declare within them are available to the rest of your scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare the variable, Python uses function scope. A variable declared in the `try` block will automatically be available afterwards if the assignment was executed without any exception:

Case 1: No Exception

```
try:
    inputFile = open( sys.argv[0] )
except IOError as e:
    print "ERROR: Could not open " + sys.argv[0]
# inputFile is opened file
```

Case 2: Exception

```
try:
    inputFile = open( sys.argv[0] )
except IOError as e:
    print "ERROR: Could not open " + sys.argv[0]
# inputFile is not defined
```

Comment: this is ONLY true if, in the try block, an exception wasn't raised before the variable in question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `with`.

```
try:
    with open(sys.argv[0]) as f:
        # operate on the file
except IOError as e:
    # handle the exception
```

Comment: So it sounds like try isn't actually a scope so I really have a non-question, but is there a reason why `with open( sys.argv[0] ) as inputFile` is better than `inputFile = open( sys.argv[0] )`?

Comment: While usually good advice, this isn't necessarily applicable. The `with` statement restricts the use of the file handle, so you couldn't, for instance, return the open file handle to a calling function.